# Is there a compelling reason to call type.mro() rather than iterate over type.__mro__ directly?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4, method-resolution-order

Is there a compelling reason to call `type.mro()` rather than iterate over `type.__mro__` directly? It's literally ~13 times faster to access (36ns vs 488 ns)

I stumbled upon it while looking to cache `type.mro()`. It seems legit, but it makes me wonder: can I rely on `type.__mro__`, or do I have to call `type.mro()`? and under what conditions can I get away with the former?

More importantly, what set of conditions would have to occur for `type.__mro__` to be invalid?

For instance, when a new subclass is defined/created that alters an existing class's mro, is the existing class' `.__mro__` immediately updated? Does this happen on every new class creation? that makes it part of class type? Which part? ..or is that what `type.mro()` is about?

Of course, all that is assuming that `type.__mro__` is, in fact, a tuple of cached names pointing to the objects in a given type's mro. If that assumption is incorrect; then, what is it? (probably a descriptor or something..) and why can/can't I use it?

EDIT: If it is a descriptor, then I'd love to learn its magic, as both: `type(type.__mro__) is tuple` and `type(type(type).__mro__) is tuple` (ie: probably not a descriptor)

EDIT: Not sure how relevant this is, but `type('whatever').mro()` returns a list whereas `type('whatever').__mro__` returns a tuple. (Un?)fortunately, appending to that list doesn't change the `__mro__` or subsequent calls to `.mro()` of/on the type in question (in this case, str).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes):

> `class.__mro__`
>
> This attribute is a tuple of classes that are considered when looking for base classes during method resolution.
>
> `class.mro()`
>
> This method can be overridden by a metaclass to customize the method resolution order for its instances. **It is called at class instantiation, and its result is stored in `__mro__`**.

So yes, your assumption about `__mro__` being a cache is correct. If your metaclass' `mro()` always returns the same thing, or if you don't have any metaclasses, you can safely use `__mro__`.